# Chi-square approximation to standard normal (0,1)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Supose that $S_n$ has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. 
Show that 
$$ \mathbb{P}(S_n \le x) = f\left(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2n}\right) $$
where $f(u)$ is the normal distribution.

I tried this: $\mathbb{P}(S_n \le x)= \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{2 S_n}-\sqrt{2 n} <= \sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2n})$
now I am trying to show that 
$\sqrt{2 S_n} - \sqrt{2n}$ converges in law to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: Please check your spelling.

Answer (score 3):

A [result due to Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Asymptotic_properties) states that the distribution of $\sqrt{2S_n}$ is approximately normal with mean $\sqrt{2n-1}$ and unit variance. Hence $\sqrt{2S_n}=\sqrt{2n-1}+Z_n$ where the distribution of $Z_n$ is approximately standard normal. Let $G$ denote the standard normal CDF. This means that
$$
[S_n\leqslant x]=[\sqrt{2S_n}\leqslant \sqrt{2x}]=[Z_n\leqslant \sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2n-1}],
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm P(S_n\leqslant x)\approx G(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{2n-1}).
$$